# In the gdb debugger, is it possible to get the function to source file mapping?

Tags: c, debugging, gdb

When stepping through code with gdb, the source file of the function currently executed is automatically presented. I would like to automate a certain debugging task (using the gdb python API) that will step into functions that are located in a user specified source path while next-ing over others (such as printf, etc..). Is there a way to access the data structure in which gdb keeps the function-to-source mapping?

Comment: You can also run the `skip file file_with_boring_functions.c` command.

Answer (score 0):

I think the closest you may get to is examining the variable or using the symbol table information with GDB.
Some of the functions that are useful are:

1) info symbol addr: 
   You can use it to find out the name of a variable or a function given its address. keep an array of dynamically linked library and decide if you want to step in or next ing the function.

2) You may @ init load all the functions in the symbol table and based on some parameters i.e externally linked libraries or internal function want to set breakpoints on them. Dumping the frame and stack @ each instance.